# MatPlotLib LaTeX не отрисовывает русские символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.6, latex

Мне нужно при помощи Python3 и MatPlotLib отобразить русские символы. Я использую следующий код, он работает с английскими символами, но не работает с русскими:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def latex_draw(tex, ri):
    print(tex)
    try:
        # Создание области отрисовки
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
        ax.set_axis_off()
        plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
        plt.rc('font', **{'family': 'verdana'})
        plt.rc('text.latex', unicode=True)
        plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}')
        plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}')
        plt.rc('text.latex', preamble='\\usepackage{amsfonts}')
        # Отрисовка формулы
        plane_text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, '$'+tex+'$', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
                             fontsize=25, color='black')
        # Определение размеров формулы
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        bbox = plane_text.get_window_extent()
        # Установка размеров области отрисовки
        fig.set_size_inches(bbox.width / 90, bbox.height / 60)  # dpi=100, но я сделал изображение побольше
        # Сохранение формулы в файл
        plt.savefig('' + str(ri) + '_result.png')
    except:
        pass
        #  Обработка ошибок

latex_draw('АБВ S', 1)
```

Этот код отрисует только "S". Я пробовал копать в сторону преамбул, но это не дало результата. Как я могу сделать это?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в тексте несколько ошибок, из-за чего не создается картинка.

Во-первых, LaTeX не дружит с русскими буквами в формулах. Вернее, подружить можно либо сторонним пакетом `mathtext` (что есть пережиток древнего LaTeX 2.09 и лучше не использовать), либо командой `\text{}` из пакета `amsmath`. Также, можно любой командой, которая выкинет из мат-моды и переведет в текстовую моду, типа всяких боксов `\mbox, \makebox` или команд смены шрифта для текста `\textrm{}, \textit{}` и т.п. Я использовал последний вариант, но это не важно. Лучше было вообще писать русский текст вне мат-моды (мат-мода - это то, что внутри "скобок" из `$`).

Во-вторых, судя по всему, Вы неправильно формируете преамбулу: в той скудной документации, что я нашел по пакету [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-customizing-py) пишут (где-то в комментариях к параметру `#text.latex.preamble :`), что преамбулу надо задавать как единую строку с разделителем в виде запятой внутри... Из чего следует неприятный вывод: конструкции вида `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` таким образом в преамбулу ввести нельзя - запятую оно рассматривает как разделитель (грубо говоря, как перенос строки для теховского исходника). Возможно, если порыться во всех rc-переменных пакета `matplotlib`, то проблему можно решить... Но мне стало лень копать глубже. С другой стороны, Вам и не нужна поддержка сразу 2х языков в данном примере (по большому счету, здесь и для одного языка мало данных). С другой стороны, если смотреть на [SO-eng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib), там советуют преамбулу вбивать немного другим способом - и это позволит использовать множественные опции пакетов LaTeX без проблем. Я ниже оставил оба варианта, просто один закомментировал.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def latex_draw(tex, ri):
    print(tex)
    try:
        # Создание области отрисовки
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
        ax.set_axis_off()
        plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
        plt.rc('font', **{'family': 'verdana'})
        plt.rc('text.latex', unicode=True)
        #plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc},\usepackage[russian]{babel},\usepackage{amsmath}')
        plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}',
            r'\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}',
            r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
        # Отрисовка формулы
        plane_text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, r'$\textrm{'+tex+r'}$', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
                         fontsize=25, color='black')
        # Определение размеров формулы
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        bbox = plane_text.get_window_extent()
        # Установка размеров области отрисовки
        fig.set_size_inches(bbox.width / 90, bbox.height / 60)  # dpi=100, но я сделал изображение побольше
        # Сохранение формулы в файл
        plt.savefig('' + str(ri) + '_result.png')
    except:
        pass
        #  Обработка ошибок
latex_draw(r'АБВ S', 1)
```

Также, для теховских команд общественность рекомендует использовать вместо обычных строк "*сырые*" (raw), вида `r'Строка'` (т.е. с префиксом r). Тогда не нужно много-много раз экранировать всякие символы, типа `\`.

И еще одно дополнение. В преамбуле не нужно указывать входную кодировку, т.к. `matplotlib` это делает сам (у него есть стандартный заголовок). Поэтому пакет `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` можно спокойно удалить из этого списка. И обратите внимание, что он использует кодировку не `utf8`, а `utf8x` - из-за этого будет конфликт, если попытаться ему скормить `utf8`.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую чуть позже